# Realm Object Server file migration critical issue

Tags: realm, realm-object-server

I've just upgraded ROS from 2.7.2 to 3.4.2. And now it becomes interesting. Our users can't open their synced realms because of error.

```
    [RLMSyncManager sharedManager].errorHandler = ^(NSError *error, RLMSyncSession *session) {
        LogError(@"RLMSyncManager error %@", error);
        if (error.code == RLMSyncErrorClientResetError)
        {
            [self backupBrokenData];
            [RLMSyncSession immediatelyHandleError:error.rlmSync_errorActionToken];
            return;
        }
    };
```

RLMSyncManager returns `Error Domain=io.realm.sync Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={underlying_error=Error Domain=io.realm.sync.auth Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={statusCode=400}}`

And that's fine seems something with our auth credentials on server. But server log tells me: `HTTP response: be33008a-ae5e-4fa1-bab2-f11b40f11b55 {"type":"https://realm.io/docs/object-server/problems/invalid-realm-type","title":"The type of the Realm file was invalid.","status":400,"code":619}`

Which is basically `You're trying to open partial file with non partial configuration`. But client and server uses same `full` realms. And no modifications happened.

Seems this error returned as false positive.

I've tried to grand administrator permission to that user. It could open his database. But as soon I remove admin permission it sees same error chain.

New users is not affected by this migration issue.

Is there anything I could do to let my users connect to their data?

Comment: Did you upgrade Realm at the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that issue was caused by bug inside realm-object-server, that was successfully fixed in version 3.4.3.

https://github.com/realm/realm-object-server/issues/374